# xsd to jaxb variables are not generated accordingly

Tags: xml, jaxb, xsd

I have an xml for which i have generate xsd file.

XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<RateQuote xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.con-way.com/XML/RateQuote.xsd"
    schemaVersion="1.0">
    <OriginZip country="US">19348</OriginZip>
    <DestinationZip country="US">97202</DestinationZip>
    <ChargeCode>P</ChargeCode>
    <Item>
        <CmdtyClass>775</CmdtyClass>
        <Weight unit="lbs">667</Weight>
        <Rate currency="USD">337.22</Rate>
        <Charge currency="USD">2249.26</Charge>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <CmdtyClass>100</CmdtyClass>
        <Weight unit="lbs">555</Weight>
        <Rate currency="USD">435.12</Rate>
        <Charge currency="USD">2414.92</Charge>
    </Item>
    <ItemTotal>
        <TotalWeight unit="lbs">1222</TotalWeight>
        <TotalCharge currency="USD">4664.18</TotalCharge>
    </ItemTotal>
    <AccessorialCharges>
        <OtherAccessorialCharges code="GUR"
            name="CON-WAY GUARANTEED!">466.42</OtherAccessorialCharges>
        <OtherAccessorialCharges code="DNC"
            name="DEST NOTIFICATION">41.25</OtherAccessorialCharges>
        <FuelSurcharge code="FSC" name="FUEL SURCHARGE 27.70%"
            rate="27.70">645.99</FuelSurcharge>
        <TotalAccessorialCharges currency="USD">1153.66</TotalAccessorialCharges>
    </AccessorialCharges>

    <Discount rate="50.0">2332.09</Discount>
    <NetCharge currency="USD">3485.75</NetCharge>
    <TransitTime>4</TransitTime>
    <EffectiveDate>11/24/14</EffectiveDate>


    <Disclaimer></Disclaimer>

    <EstDeliverDate>12/02/14</EstDeliverDate>
    <SpecialSavings></SpecialSavings>

</RateQuote>
```

**XSD file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="RateQuote">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="OriginZip">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:attribute name="country" type="xsd:string" />
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="DestinationZip">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:attribute name="country" type="xsd:string" />
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="ChargeCode" type="xsd:string" />
        <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Item">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="CmdtyClass" type="xsd:int" />
              <xsd:element name="Weight">
                <xsd:complexType>
                  <xsd:attribute name="unit" type="xsd:string" />
                </xsd:complexType>
              </xsd:element>
              <xsd:element name="Rate">
                <xsd:complexType>
                  <xsd:attribute name="currency" type="xsd:string" />
                </xsd:complexType>
              </xsd:element>
              <xsd:element name="Charge">
                <xsd:complexType>
                  <xsd:attribute name="currency" type="xsd:string" />
                </xsd:complexType>
              </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="ItemTotal">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="TotalWeight">
                <xsd:complexType>
                  <xsd:attribute name="unit" type="xsd:string" />
                </xsd:complexType>
              </xsd:element>
              <xsd:element name="TotalCharge">
                <xsd:complexType>
                  <xsd:attribute name="currency" type="xsd:string" />
                </xsd:complexType>
              </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="AccessorialCharges">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="OtherAccessorialCharges">
                <xsd:complexType>
                  <xsd:attribute name="code" type="xsd:string" />
                  <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" />
                </xsd:complexType>
              </xsd:element>
              <xsd:element name="FuelSurcharge">
                <xsd:complexType>
                  <xsd:attribute name="code" type="xsd:string" />
                  <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" />
                  <xsd:attribute name="rate" type="xsd:decimal" />
                </xsd:complexType>
              </xsd:element>
              <xsd:element name="TotalAccessorialCharges">
                <xsd:complexType>
                  <xsd:attribute name="currency" type="xsd:string" />
                </xsd:complexType>
              </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="Discount">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:attribute name="rate" type="xsd:decimal" />
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="NetCharge">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:attribute name="currency" type="xsd:string" />
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="TransitTime" type="xsd:int" />
        <xsd:element name="EffectiveDate" type="xsd:dateTime" />
        <xsd:element name="Disclaimer" type="xsd:string" />
        <xsd:element name="EstDeliverDate" type="xsd:dateTime" />
        <xsd:element name="SpecialSavings" type="xsd:string" />
      </xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:attribute name="xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:attribute name="schemaVersion" type="xsd:decimal" />
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

But when i generated JAXB classes in eclipse.

**NetCharge class gets created with a variable string "currency" but there is no variable for value.**

This happens to all other classes where value and attribute are used.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML Schema does not allow textual content in `NetCharge`, only the attribute. You probably need a complex type with a simple content here:

> [Meaning of xsd:simpleContent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660979/meaning-of-xsdsimplecontent)

Try the following:

```
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="string">
        <xs:attribute name="currency" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
```

Should generate a `content` property.